# Create facebook login callback in separate class

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have the following facebook callback, but I would like to register it in the seperate class (e.g FacebookConnector), not in the MainActivity function (the similar scheme I would like to use for any facebook API connection):

```
    facebookLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            //do something
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            System.err.println("Login cancel");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException e) {
            System.err.println("Error on login");
        }
    });
```

In main MainActivity function I would like to create some handler that would have the following code inside:

```
facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector();
if (facebookConnector.successfulLogin()) {
     //do something
}
```

where `successfulLogin` method would return true or false. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I would do if I were you:
In `FacebookConnector` I would put:

```
public FacebookCallback<LoginResult> getFacebookCallBack() {
    return new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(final LoginResult loginResult) {
            //Some code here
            myActivity.successfulLogin();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            //Some code here
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            //Some code here
        }
    };
}
```

I would also put in the constructor of `FacbookConnector`:

```
public void FacebookConnector(MainActivity myActivity){
        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        FacebookCallback<LoginResult> mFacebookCallBack = getFacebookCallBack();
        fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mFacebookCallBack);
        this.myActivity = myActivity;
}
```

Where `fbLoginButton` has the reference to the FB Login Button. I would also register a Callback in the `FacebookConnector`

Next, in your `MainActivity`, I would put:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//Your code
    FacebookConnector facebookConnector = new FacebookConnector(context);
}

public void successfulLogin(){
//Code for what you want to do.
}
```

This same thing could have been done by using a CallBack-Listener mechanism, although I don't see the difference as such. 
Hope that helps. Let me know if you require any clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I also didn't want to use CallBack-Listener mechanism. So your solution worked perfect for me!!